# Get id and value of dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm trying to get the ids of dynamically created elements, now these elements are in the form of input fields that can be modified by the user (the user enters the number of players then he gets input fields to type in their names), I'm trying to get their values as well, here is what I'm trying to do:

```
// Creating the input fields
const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');
const parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  const newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");

  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
}

// Trying to access them
const players = document.getElementById('player-list').children;
console.log(players.value);
```

Comment: Why not initialise *players* as an array before the for loop then *push* each "player" into it as they're created? Or give them a unique class (say "player") and get them with `document.querySelectorAll('.player')`. You could also use `document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=player]')` to get input elements with ID starting with "player".

Comment: @RobG how can I get their values if I do : "document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=player]')" because .value isn't working.

Comment: It returns a static [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) that you can then iterate over to get the values using [*forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to go about it:

1. Add the inputs to an array as you create them
2. Add a unique class to each player input then use `document.querySelectorAll('.className')`
3. Select the inputs based on inputs with ID starting with "player"

E.g. the following just adds "Player i" as the value of each input, but it could do other things.

```js
// Creating the input fields
// const x = localStorage.getItem('playersNum');
let x = 3;
let parentDiv = document.getElementById('player-list');
for (let i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  let newInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newInput.setAttribute("type", "text");
  newInput.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  newInput.setAttribute("id", `player${i}`);
  newInput.setAttribute("placeholder", "Player's Name");
  parentDiv.appendChild(newInput);
  parentDiv.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
}

// Get a static NodeList of inputs with ID starting with "player"
let players = document.querySelectorAll('input[id^=player]');
// Iterate over list, adding a value
players.forEach((player, i) => player.value = 'Player ' + i);
```

```css
div {border: 1px solid #aaaaaa}
```

```html
<div id="player-list">
</div>
```

You can reduce your code somewhat by:

1. The default type is "text" so no need to set it
2. Set attributes using property access
3. Append inputs as they're created

so:

```
let newInput = parentDiv.appendChild(document.createElement("INPUT"));
newInput.class = 'form-control';
newInput.id = `player${i}`;
newInput.placeholder = 'Player\'s Name';
```

I'm not a fan of using a place holder as the label, much better to have an actual label and use the placeholder as a hint, so:

```
<label for="player0">Name player 0:<input id="player0" class="form-control"></label>
```

or similar.

Comment: I tried doing that, how can I get their values and store them in some sort of an array.

Comment: The answer shows how to loop over the nodes and set the value. To create an array of the values, do exactly the same thing and push the value into an array like `valueArray.push(player.value)`. You could also do `let values  = Array.from(players).map(player => player.value)`.